# SQL Select Value From Comma Delimited List

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in my database called "Notes". It contains a comma delimited list of values.

I want to perform a SELECT Query that only returns the first value in the "Notes" field.

This query would also return additional fields from the database.

for example

```
SELECT Name, Phone, Notes (only the first value)
FROM Table1
```

Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: Sounds like your 'Notes' column is really a one-to-many data relationship. Any chance you can change your schema to split the comma-seperated data in 'Notes' into rows in a seperate table? MUCH easier to query that way. Performance will be better too - the query you describe will require string manipulation and result in a 'table scan' which will only get worse as your table grows in size.

Comment: There is a similar question about tokenizing strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209658/transact-sql-how-do-i-tokenize-a-string

Comment: Not my notes column, someone else's and I am unfortunately stuck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT Name, Phone, SUBSTRING(Notes, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Notes)) AS first_value
FROM Table1
```

**Demo**

```
DECLARE @csv varchar(50)
SET @csv = 'comma after this, and another,'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@csv, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @csv)) AS first_value
```

**Result**

```
|      first_value |
--------------------
| comma after this |
```

As mentioned in the comments, you should normalize your structure and not have more than one value stored in a single attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't your substrings start at 1?

Comment: @JordanKaye Manual states *"If start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in expression"*. So I assume `0` will go to `1`.

Comment: True, but since SQL strings are generally 1-indexed it probably makes sense to treat them as such. Prevents confusion when using other functions like CHARINDEX.

Comment: If there is only one note, this returns BLANK instead of the note... see my answer. *(unless of course, even a single note is ended with comma)*

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name, Phone, Left(Notes, CharIndex(',', Notes + ',')) FirstNote
  FROM Table1
```

You need the `Notes + ','` bit in the CharIndex to work correctly - see this example (I have included njk's answer)

```
with Table1(Name, Phone, Notes) as (
    select 'abc', '123', 'Some,notes,here' union all
    select 'abd', '124', 'Single-note' union all
    select 'abe', '125', '' union all
    select 'syz', '126', null
)
---
SELECT Name, Phone, Left(Notes, CharIndex(',', Notes + ',')-1) FirstNote
       ,SUBSTRING(Notes, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Notes)) AS njk
  FROM Table1
```

Results

```
Name Phone FirstNote       njk
---- ----- --------------- ---------------
abc  123   Some            Some
abd  124   Single-note     
abe  125                   
syz  126   NULL            NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,
   phones, 
   split_part(notes, ',', 1) as first_notes  
FROM Table1
```

solutions for Select Value From Comma Delimited List

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a more general answer (not just the first field but an arbitrarily specified one) so I modified Kermit's answer and put it in a function. Here it is in case it helps save somebody else time

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetFieldXFromDelimitedList] (@SearchIn nvarchar(max)
    , @Delimiter char(1), @FieldNum int ) RETURNS nvarchar(max) as BEGIN
/*
fnGetFieldXFromDelimitedList(@SearchIn, @Delimiter, @FieldNum)
Returns the Nth value (specified by @FieldNum, first is 1 not 0)
    from @SearchIn assuming @SearchIn is a list of multiple values
    delimited by @Delimiter

DECLARE @SearchIn nvarchar(max) = 'F1, Field 2, F3,, F5, F6, F7'
DECLARE @Delimiter char(1) = ','
DECLARE @FieldNum int = 7
--*/
--SELECT dbo.fnGetFieldXFromDelimitedList ('F1, Field 2, F3,, F5, F6, F7', ',', 5)
DECLARE @PosStart int = 1 --SUBSTRING(SearchIn, StartPos, StrLen) considers 1 the first character
DECLARE @PosEnd INT = LEN(@SearchIn)
DECLARE @TempString nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(@SearchIn, @Delimiter)
DECLARE @TempNum INT = 1
DECLARE @RetVal nvarchar(max) = ''

--SElECT SUBSTRING(@SearchIn, 1, 1) 
SET @PosEnd = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TempString, @PosStart + LEN(@Delimiter))
WHILE @TempNum < @FieldNum AND @PosStart > 0 AND @PosStart < LEN(@TempString) BEGIN
    SET @PosStart = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TempString, @PosStart) + LEN(@Delimiter)
    SET @PosEnd = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @TempString, @PosStart)
    SET @TempNum = @TempNum + 1
    --SELECT @PosStart, @PosEnd , @TempNum 
END --WHILE

IF @TempNum = @FieldNum AND @PosEnd > 0 BEGIN
    SET @RetVal = SUBSTRING(@TempString, @PosStart, @PosEnd - @PosStart)
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @RetVal = NULL
END

--SELECT @RetVal
RETURN @RetVal
END
```