# Split string by space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I am trying to use a result of a string split to where close in my sql condition

I have table which has a `varchar` column. I am trying to filter the result where there is only one word is presented.

eg. if the table have values like *'ABC DEF','XYZ','EGF HIJ'* and I am expecting to get only *'XYZ'* as result.

I am not sure what to use here, though splitting the each value in column will be a one way. But not sure how I can use it as a condition

I had look some split samples like below.

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) ='Test Word'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Str ) - 1) AS [First],
       SUBSTRING(@Str , CHARINDEX(' ', @Str ) + 1, LEN(@Str )) AS [Last]
```

Comment: This answer could help you (if you insist going the "string split" path): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209658/transact-sql-how-do-i-tokenize-a-string

Comment: @tEsTA that has nothing to do with this question (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @Hogan: "I am not sure what to use here, though **splitting** each value in column will be one way". So I agree is not **needed**, but it does have *something* to do with this question (it's one possible, even if cumbersome, way of solving it).

Comment: @Hogan: by the way, that's what "tokenize" means.

Comment: No need to be snide esp. when you are wrong.  It is not what tokenize means.  Consider this string:   "`1+1=2`"  The tokens here have nothing to do with spaces.

Comment: Should this question need a downvote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get only 'XYZ' in the with a column containing

```
tableName.fieldName
'ABC DEF'
'XYZ'
'EGF HIJ'
```

Do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',fieldname) = 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be CHARINDEX(' ',fieldname) = 0?

Comment: Used `WHERE CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim(rtrim(fieldname))) = 0` which works fine !

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - You got it.  `=0` will give you items with one word, `>0` will give you items with two words -- and yes, if you have leading in or trailing spaces those will need to be removed.

Answer (score 7):

***This is also work***

```
select SUBSTRING(EmpName,0,CHARINDEX(' ',EmpName)),SUBSTRING(EmpName,CHARINDEX(' ',EmpName),LEN(EMPNAME)) 
from tblemployee
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (string VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @table VALUES ('ABC DEF')
INSERT @table VALUES ('XYZ')
INSERT @table VALUES ('EGF HIJ')

SELECT * FROM @table
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', string) = 0
```