# split lat and long out of string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string and I need to split the lat and long values out of it, how can I do this in sql code

example of one of the strings? I want to save the 2 values into 2 columns in my database.

> Canada: Manitoba  53.760861   -98.813876

Comment: Are every lines formatted this exact way?
COUNTRY: PROVINCE/STATE ###.###### ###.######?

Comment: Tokenise the string. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209658/transact-sql-how-do-i-tokenize-a-string

Comment: No some have just state, but the lat and long are always at the end of the string and the second number always has a - before it and the first number is always 2 digits then a fullstop .

Comment: Ah.. in which case.. using my solution to lookup for '.' can work better (I provided a solution with the space). The main difference will be the first lookup charindex('.', STRING, 1) and in the SUBSTRING(STRING, theX - 3, theY - TheX -3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as formatting is consistent, this should get you what you want:

```
DECLARE @ValueToParse VARCHAR(255) = 'Canada: Manitoba 53.760861 -98.813876', @Latitude VARCHAR(25), @Longitude VARCHAR(25)
SELECT  @Latitude = SUBSTRING(@ValueToParse, (PATINDEX('% -%',@ValueToParse) - 9), 9),
        @Longitude = SUBSTRING(@ValueToParse, PATINDEX('% -%',@ValueToParse) + 1, 11)
SELECT @Latitude, @Longitude
```

If you want to parse the column 'ColumnWithDataToSplit' which contains the lat/long data in it, from the table 'YourTable' then do this:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnWithDataToSplit, 
    SUBSTRING(ColumnWithDataToSplit, (PATINDEX('% -%',ColumnWithDataToSplit) - 9), 9) AS [Latitude],
    SUBSTRING(ColumnWithDataToSplit, PATINDEX('% -%',ColumnWithDataToSplit) + 1, 11) AS [Longitude]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: ah that worked great for the example, but I have a table full of them to split, how can I swap the text for the column name in a table?

Comment: How would it work should the long/lag not be negative? You're looking for this pattern : ' -%'

Comment: In a comment, the OP stated that the second number would ALWAYS have a '-' before it.

Comment: See latest edit for doing this from a table for multiple records

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it didn't split correct then

Comment: In what way? If the pattern ' -' is in there twice, it won't work...hard to know without knowing what data failed/how it failed/etc.

Comment: actually tinkered with the numbers and whitespace that that example now works thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TheX INT
DECLARE @TheY INT

SELECT @theX= CHARINDEX(' ', STRING, 2)

SELECT @TheY = CHARINDEX(' ', STRING, CHARINDEX(' ', STRING, 1) + 1)

SELECT      SUBSTRING(STRING, @TheX , @TheY - @TheX - 1) AS X, 
            SUBSTRING(STRING, @TheY) AS Y
```

I only separated the variables for ease of reading. Using SUBSTRING is one way, but perhaps more efficient tokenizing.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so the "string" is the value I want to split, what is the @text meant to be?

Comment: I cant get this example working with the column name from my table

Comment: Replacing the STRING by your column name?