# Improve my SQL query for search

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help improve my SQL Query. It is for a site search. Below is the Query:

```
SELECT j_author.author_id as authorID, author_name, author_description, author_cat, author_city, author_state, points, (SELECT SUM(rate_value) FROM j_rating WHERE j_rating.author_id = authorID ) AS rating_value
    FROM j_author
    JOIN j_author_category ON j_author.author_cat = j_author_category.author_cat_id
    WHERE author_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
    OR author_city LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'
    ORDER BY rating_value DESC
```

It works but it's not exactly what I want. For example, if I search for 'edu' and there's an author or city named educate, it returns the author or city. but if "educated people" is searched for, it returns no result.

I've also tried using:

```
SELECT j_author.author_id as authorID, author_name, author_description, author_cat, author_city, author_state, points, (SELECT SUM(rate_value) FROM j_rating WHERE j_rating.author_id = authorID ) AS rating_value,             
MATCH(j_author.author_name, j_author.author_city) AGAINST ('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM j_author  
JOIN j_author_category ON j_author.author_cat = j_author_category.author_cat_id
WHERE MATCH(j_author.author_name, j_author.author_city) AGAINST ('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

But every time I use this method, when I search for 'edu', it doesn't return any result.

What I want is if "educated people" is the search keyword entered, it should search using both "educated" and "people" as separate key words and return a result matching any of the keywords. Also, when 'edu' is the keyword, it should return all authors with edu in their name or city

Comment: fulltext search doesn't look for "substring" matches. it looks for words, not parts of words. if you want to search for partial matches, you need to search for `edu*`

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible for you to break apart the text before passing the values into the query, something like this may be what you're looking for:

[Transact-SQL: How do I tokenize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209658/transact-sql-how-do-i-tokenize-a-string)

If you break apart the query on pre-determined characters and perform a query on each "token", you should be able to accomplish your goal.